# CUDA Thrust Min_Element result equals 0

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

Very new to CUDA and C++ however have been working away at some problems I have noticed. I am wanting to generate the smallest number as well as the index in CUDA. Currently I have

```
    __global__ void updateGB2(Particle *dev_p) {
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x *blockDim.x;

    globalB[i] = dev_p[i].localBest;

    double *result = thrust::min_element(thrust::device,globalB, globalB + pSize);
    printf("%lf", result);
}
```

And this method is being called, however the result is only printing 0.0000. I am probably missing some information for using thrust but from the information I have read I am unsure what else to do.
globalB is defined as **device** and Particle is passed from CPU to GPU.

Comment: irrespective of whatever else is broken (please read  [MCVE]), what do you hope to achieve by trying to print a pointer as a floating point value?

Comment: I want to print the minimum element from globalB.

Comment: min_element doesn't return the minimum element. It returns an iterator(pointer) to the minimum element. There is a significant difference between those two things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the thrust [documentation](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__extrema.html#gab6f4900fa17fa2c6596eea628b6055b7)

> min_element finds the smallest element in the range [first, last). It
>   returns the first iterator i in [first, last) such that no other
>   iterator in [first, last) points to a value smaller than *i.

In your code, that means that `result` is a pointer which must be de-referenced  in order to access the minimum value. A complete example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

__global__ void updateGB2(double *data, int pSize) {
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x *blockDim.x;

    double* globalB = data + (i * pSize);
    double* result = thrust::min_element(thrust::device, globalB, globalB + pSize);
    printf("%d %lf\n", i, *result);
}

int main() 
{
    const int pSize = 16;
    const int Nvectors = 32;
    const int Nvals = Nvectors * pSize;

    {
        thrust::device_vector<double> dv(Nvals);

        thrust::counting_iterator<double> counter(10);
        thrust::copy(counter, counter+Nvals, dv.begin());

        double* d_h = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dv.data());
        updateGB2<<<1, Nvectors>>>(d_h, pSize);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }
    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

which compiles and runs like so:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -o thrustdevice thrustdevice.cu 
$ ./thrustdevice 
0 10.000000
1 26.000000
2 42.000000
3 58.000000
4 74.000000
5 90.000000
6 106.000000
7 122.000000
8 138.000000
9 154.000000
10 170.000000
11 186.000000
12 202.000000
13 218.000000
14 234.000000
15 250.000000
16 266.000000
17 282.000000
18 298.000000
19 314.000000
20 330.000000
21 346.000000
22 362.000000
23 378.000000
24 394.000000
25 410.000000
26 426.000000
27 442.000000
28 458.000000
29 474.000000
30 490.000000
31 506.000000
```